# Trying to forward some paths to a specific container with nginx but it keeps taking me to the root path

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

So I have 3 containers: `nginx`, `wordpress` and `special-container`. I would like `special-container` to handle two specific paths of my domain and `wordpress` to handle everything else. Below is my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=0;

    location = /special_path_1 {
      return 301 /special_path_1/;
    }

    location /special_path_1/ {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://special-container:200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location = /special_path_2 {
      return 301 /special_path_2/;
    }

    location /special_path_2/ {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://special-container:201;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

When I run `curl http://special-container:200` inside container `nginx`, I can see the correct response from `special-container`. However, when I visit `https://example.com/special_path_1` with Chrome, I just keep getting redirected to `https://example.com`. Clearing cookies and using incognito does not help. But when I visit some random path like `https://example.com/asdfsa`, I see a 404 page returned by wordpress. Everything else on wordpress is also working fine.

Below is the log from `nginx`:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:21 +0800] "GET /special_path_1 HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:21 +0800] "GET /special_path_1/ HTTP/2.0" 307 37 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:22 +0800] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 36865 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:22 +0800] "GET /wp-includes/blocks/navigation/style.min.css?ver=6.1.1 HTTP/2.0" 200 15342 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:22 +0800] "GET /wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=6.1.1 HTTP/2.0" 200 18617 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:22 +0800] "GET /wp-content/themes/livro/style.css?ver=1.0.19 HTTP/2.0" 200 6052 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:22 +0800] "GET /wp-includes/blocks/navigation/view.min.js?ver=c24330f635f5cb9d5e0e HTTP/2.0" 200 1144 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:22 +0800] "GET /wp-includes/blocks/navigation/view-modal.min.js?ver=45f05135277abf0b0408 HTTP/2.0" 200 7779 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:23 +0800] "GET /wp-content/themes/livro/assets/fonts/Newsreader.woff2 HTTP/2.0" 200 214880 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:23 +0800] "GET /wp-content/themes/livro/assets/fonts/Newsreader-italic.woff2 HTTP/2.0" 200 239844 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"



XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:38 +0800] "GET /asdfsa HTTP/2.0" 404 35922 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:39 +0800] "GET /wp-includes/blocks/navigation/style.min.css?ver=6.1.1 HTTP/2.0" 200 15342 "https://example.com/asdfsa" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:39 +0800] "GET /wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=6.1.1 HTTP/2.0" 200 18617 "https://example.com/asdfsa" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:39 +0800] "GET /wp-content/themes/livro/style.css?ver=1.0.19 HTTP/2.0" 200 6052 "https://example.com/asdfsa" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:39 +0800] "GET /wp-includes/blocks/navigation/view.min.js?ver=c24330f635f5cb9d5e0e HTTP/2.0" 200 1144 "https://example.com/asdfsa" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:39 +0800] "GET /wp-includes/blocks/navigation/view-modal.min.js?ver=45f05135277abf0b0408 HTTP/2.0" 200 7779 "https://example.com/asdfsa" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:39 +0800] "GET /wp-content/themes/livro/assets/fonts/Newsreader.woff2 HTTP/2.0" 200 214880 "https://example.com/asdfsa" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [26/Mar/2023:01:29:57 +0800] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 47 "https://example.com/wp-admin/theme-install.php?search=Quadrat" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Why am I getting a 307 redirect here? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

=== Edit ===

Result of `curl -I --location https://example.com/special_path_1`:

```
HTTP/2 301 
server: nginx
date: Sat, 25 Mar 2023 17:11:59 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 162
location: https://example.com/special_path_1/
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
content-security-policy: default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'
strict-transport-security: max-age=0

HTTP/2 404 
server: nginx
date: Sat, 25 Mar 2023 17:11:59 GMT
content-type: text/plain
content-length: 18
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
content-security-policy: default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'
```

Comment: Would you please try again with `curl -I --location https://example.com/special_path_1` and update the question with the result?

Comment: Also please add the nginx `access.log`.

Comment: @Andromeda Could you be more specific about what I should be looking for? I already pasted the 4 lines that I think are important and the rest is just lots of wordpress requests

Comment: I just want to tshoot. Let me provide an answer and find out if it worked.

Comment: Have you tried using your proxy pass in the "/" root location to see if it works (instead of wp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a `/` at the end of `proxy_pass` to special-container. `proxy_pass http://special-container:200/`. Without `/` makes this happen when you request to `https://example.com/special_path_1` this request sends to `http://special-container:200/special_path_1` then got 404 and with `/` make this happen this request send to `http://special-container:200/` then got 200.

This part must be like:

```
location /special_path_1/ {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://special-container:200/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```